# Dynamic Buttons are not triggering in aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have recently started making a mock webstore for an assignment and have unfortunately hit a road bump over a button. I have tried MULTIPLE ways to implement a button that would trigger a function via my server. However, I cannot get the button to trigger via the server side no matter how I implement a button. Below is my code for my aspx.cs page. Note the AddPanel() function is where I am trying to add each panel to my webpage with the corresponding css. If yall need the css as well I'm more than happy to provide it. Any help is appreciated. I also kept all the comment's of variations I have tried to get my button to work.

Homepage.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class Homepage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private List<Item> theItems;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(theItems == null)
    {
        theItems = new List<Item>();
    }
    Item it = new Item("img/demo/1.jpg", "img/demo/thumb1.jpg", "Hard Drive 500GB", "Nothing but the highest quality of hard drives.", 600.50, "#1", 2);
    theItems.Add(it);
    it = new Item("img/demo/2.jpg", "img/demo/thumb2.jpg", "External Blu Ray", "You like blu ray? We can play Blu ray.", 200.00, "#2", 8);
    theItems.Add(it);
    it = new Item("img/demo/3.jpg", "img/demo/thumb3.jpg", "Fancy Phone", "Wanna call someone? You need a phone to do it!", 499.99, "#3", 2);
    theItems.Add(it);
    it = new Item("img/demo/4.jpg", "img/demo/thumb4.jpg", "Throwable Frisbee", "Who needs a laptop when you have a frisbee!", 2000.99, "#4", 2);
    theItems.Add(it);
    it = new Item("img/demo/5.jpg", "img/demo/thumb5.jpg", "Test Div", "This is a test div yo lets hope it works", 5.01, "#5", 5);
    theItems.Add(it);
    AddPanel();
}

//public void AddPanel(string imgSrc, string thmbSrc, string label, string description, string href, double price)
public void AddPanel()
{
    int count = 1;
    Button btn = new Button();
    foreach(Item item in theItems)
    {

        string btnID = "button" + count;
        btn.ID = btnID;
        btn.Text = "Add To Cart";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(addToCart);

        string pane = @"<div><img src=""" + item.ImgSrc + @""" alt=""""><h5>" + item.Label + "</h5><p>" + item.Description + "</p>";
        pane += @"<p style=""text-align: right; margin-right: 16px""><a href = ""#"" class=""button"">Add to Cart</a></p></div>";
        //pane += @"<p style=""text-align: right; margin-right: 16px"">""</p></div>";
        //pane += @"<p style=""text-align: right; margin-right: 16px"">< asp:Button ID = """+btnID+@""" runat = ""server"" Text = ""Add To Cart"" /></p></div>";
        //pane += @"<p style=""text-align: right; margin-right: 16px""><input type=""button"" id="""+ btnID + @""" runat=""server"" text=""Add To Cart"" onServerClick=""addToCart()""></button></p></div>";
            //pane += @"<p style=""text-align: right; margin-right: 16px""><a id="""+btnID+ @""" href = """" class=""button"" runat=""server"" onServerClick=""addToCart"">Add to Cart</a></p></div>";
            this.panes.InnerHtml += pane;
            string paneNav = @"<li><a href=""" + item.Href + @"""><img src=""" + item.ThmbNailSrc + @""" alt=""""> <strong>" + item.Label + "</strong>" + "$" + item.Price + "</a></li>";
            this.innerPaneNav.InnerHtml += paneNav;
            count++;
        }

    }

    public void addToCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s;
    s = "It worked!"; // this is where I have a breakpoint to see if the     code was triggered
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the button by c# code behind, You can not add this by html Codes! To adding button created to the panel you need to add this:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(addToCart); // your code
pane.Controls.Add(btn); //adding created button to server side control (pane)
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well but I get an error as soon as I add the button to the controls that says "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot get inner content of panes because the contents are not literal."

Comment: What is the **panes**? It is not in your code. The error says *Cannot get inner content of panes* . Because of this i think the problem is with this line: `this.panes.InnerHtml += pane;` You can easily use a `div` element with an attribute `runat="server"` and add html text or c# controls to that.